# OpenLayers - ModifyFeature - How to label vertices with a progressive number

Tags: javascript, labeling, openlayers-2

I am quite new in OpenLayers and JavaScript.

I have a control `ModifyFeature` on a path vector layer.

I would like the vertices to be rendered with a stylemap label showing their progressive number (1,2,3,4,etc..), the same sequence they are stored within the linestring.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra attribute to the vector layer (numSeq) to hold the global count of features. Later register a featureadded listener and add an "number" attribute to be used as the label of the point.

You can find valuable examples at: http://acanimal.github.io/Openlayers-Cookbook/ showing how to style features using attributes (see chp07 - Improving style using StyleMap and feature's attributes replacement) and listening for events (chp04 Listening for vector layer features' events)

Next code http://jsfiddle.net/mEy8x/1/ shows an example working for points. For polylines and polygons you need to improve the code.

Comment: Thanks Eric, but my problem is related to label vertices of the same feature (linestring), not labelling each feature of a vector layer. In my case I cannot add an attribute for each vertex of the linestring. I already checked the link you suggested and it does not work for my scope...at least I am not able to make it working for vertices. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a new property for the each point of the vertices, like in you case now you are using a path so you can iterate through each the vertices in this path and define a new property, check below example:

```
var ft = feature; //linestring feature;
var comps = ft.geometry.components; //getting vertices in linestring

for (var i = 0; i < comps.components.length; i++) {
     comp.components[i].newProp= i; //define a new property and give any name you like (like here I define **newProp** )
}
```